# "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved"

Tags: java, eclipse, build, tomcat7

Trying to import the source of jforum into eclipse, works so so, but I get aforementioned error "project cannot blabla..".

I found several threads about this specific error message, but none of them helped me so far.

Here is a screenshot of the error message and I believe it's easily fixed since it's simply a matter of a configuration (or lack thereof):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIoF3.png

I just did a clean install of Eclipse, and I'm thinking I might have forgotten to setup the Tomcat server? Or are there actual java libraries that needs to be copied over somewhere?

thx in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You classpath seems to expect a variable TOMCAT_HOME

If this variable is expected then you can define that in

`Preferences > Java>Build Path > Classpath Variables.`

Add a new variable with name TOMCAT_HOME and the path should be your tomcat home directory. All these jars that are missing should be present in the tomcat lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

**From Screenshot I realize You are going with class path variable which is no longer valid**

> Goto Eclipe -> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables

check the aboved jar files are present or not. Add/Edit if required so.